# C# : WebSocket Handshake

Tags: c#, websocket, handshake

C# WebSocket Handshake

I can't extract the numbers from a key in my method, because of an Exception.

The Exception says the following:
System.FormatException: "Input string was not in a correct format."

```
    public static byte[] GenerateResponseToken(string key1, string key2, byte[] request_token)
    {
        int part1 = (int)(ExtractNums(key1) / CountSpaces(key1));
        int part2 = (int)(ExtractNums(key2) / CountSpaces(key2));
        byte[] key1CalcBytes = ReverseBytes(BitConverter.GetBytes(part1));
        byte[] key2CalcBytes = ReverseBytes(BitConverter.GetBytes(part2));
        byte[] sum = key1CalcBytes
                    .Concat(key2CalcBytes)
                    .Concat(request_token).ToArray();

        return new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(sum);
    }



    public static long ExtractNums(string key)
    {
        string number = "";
        char[] array = key.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsNumber(array[i]))
            {
                number += array[i];
            }
        }
        return long.Parse(number);
    }
```

The Exception is in the "return long.Parse(number);" Line.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use a debugger to check the value of `number`. It probably has non-digit characters, or is empty.

Comment: you can wrap `long.Parse` with `try` `catch` and re-throw `number` value if parsing fails. There is `long.TryParse()` also

Comment: please check with TryParse Instead , and also print number in console/log before parsing to make sure you're getting proper long value